# How to configure name of the view without returning it explicitly or modifying a parameter of method in the controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

There is a couple of ways to introduce a method in spring `@Controller`. I.e. when nothing spring related is used in its signature.
I.e. a method whose return type is the actual result of operation and parameters contain no flow related staff. Just pure logic apart from spring annotations. This is a simple controller which always routes to a single view.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list/{day}")
@ModelAttribute("list")
public List<String> list(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date day) {
    System.out.println("list of somthing for the day of "+day);
    return Arrays.asList("a,b,c,d".split(","));
}
```

Note, view name is nowhere mentioned but resolved somehow (I'm new to spring and have no idea how). This results in error 404 if method is accessed from the browser i.e. `http://localhost/test/list/2015-01-01`. Error is 404 "/test/WEB-INF/jsp/list/2015-01-01.jsp" not found.

What i'd like to achive: that this particular method would use /test/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp as a view. I guess it should be annotated, but I failed to find in docs how. What am I missing?

Comment: In other words qeustion is:
_How to configure name of the view without returning it explicitly or modifying a parameter?_

Answer (score 0):

> What i'd like to achive: that this particular method would use
>   /test/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp as a view

For this you have to create a dispatcher like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    ">

    <!-- the same thing is done with the AppConfig class with the annotation @ComponentScan(basePackages="" -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

your web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

And in your method (inside the controller ) you return the view name like that :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list/{day}")
public ModelAndView list(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date day) {
    System.out.println("list of somthing for the day of "+day);
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("list");
    model.addObject("list",Arrays.asList("a,b,c,d".split(","))) 
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid returning ( or taking as parameter) spring related objects? ModelAndView in particular.

Comment: No, it is not answered. I still dont understand how to configure view name without returning it explicitly?